# Try to get bootstrap 4 datetimepicker to work in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get the datetimepicker to work in a modal popup but it is not working correctly. When I click on the input field, the date/time picker widget does come up, but it is behind the modal window. If I try and select a different date, the picker closes immediately and does not update the input form.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="historicalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="HisModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="HisModalLabel">Historical Device Tracking</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="His-modal-body">
                <div class="form-check" id="historical_form">
                    <!--<div class="historical_track"  ></div>-->
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="padding:20px">
                    Enter Date/Time Start and Finish to Track
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime" placeholder="Select date/time" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start_historical_tracking" data-dismiss="modal">Start Historical Tracking</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

And here is the js:

```
$(function () {
  //default date range picker
  $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
      autoApply:true
  });

  //date time picker
  $('#datetime').daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      locale: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
      }
  });

  //single date
  $('#date').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
  });
});
```

And here is what I see on the screen:
[image]

All the web tutorials make this seem like such a simple widget. But it has me pulling my hair out.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got some missing ending divs and also an h5 element that is trying close an h4, also maybe some script tags are out of order? That will cause some wackiness. This isn't 100% your exact code, and you will need to adjust some of the css, but it is a working version of what you are attempting. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ok2r9m8/4/), I hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
  //default date range picker
  $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
      autoApply:true
  });

  //date time picker
  $('#datetime').daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      locale: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
      }
  });

  //single date
  $('#date').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
    Button
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Historical Device Tracking</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-check" id="historical_form">
            <!--<div class="historical_track"  ></div>-->
          </div>
          <div style="padding:20px">
            Enter Date/Time Start and Finish to Track
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime" placeholder="Select date/time" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hi Jon,

Thank you so much! You solved my problems. It seems that the css I was using was messing me up. Using the css files you included in your example fixed my issues. Problem solved. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!! If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer as the solution, that will help out any future developers :)